# How to access mongodb replicaset hosted on a kubernetes cluster from outside?

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, rancher

Cluster created in Rancher with Amazon EKS.

MongoDB replicaset was created as a catalog app in Rancher.

Services in the cluster can successfully connect the the database with this connection string.

`mongodb://mongodb-replicaset.mongodb-replicaset.svc.cluster.local:27017/tradeit_system?replicaSet=rs`

I want to view and edit data in the db. In a local db you can do it easily by the command `mongo --port 27017`.

Similarly is there a way to connect to the one one on kubernetes. Either from the terminal or using an application like Robo 3t?

EDIT

The replicaset doesn't show when I do.

`kubectl get deployments --all-namespace`

`kubectl get pods --all-namespaces`

Show that it runs in 3 pods mongodb-replicaset-0, mongodb-replicaset-1, mongodb-replicaset-2.

Answer (score 6):

1. run `kubectl get services -n <namespace>`. this will list the replicaset service
2. execute `kubectl port-forward svc/mongodb-replicaset -n mongoNamespace 27018:27017`

where

**mongodb-replicaset** = mongodb service name

**mongoNamespace** = namespace

and **27018** = your local port

As best practice, you should always connect on services not on pods. Since pods are automatically recreated/restarted, it will give you a new pod name. Connecting to a service saves you from reconnecting and finding the primary pod of your mongodb replicaset.

Comment: @may you right, connecting to the service is the best rather than the pods.

Comment: Should I use a service to access my mongodb cluster on my microservice too?

Comment: @VandersonAssis yes especially if you connect your db server on your microservices. rather than connecting them to a specific pod. there are 3types of services on k8s, ClusterIP, NodePort and LoadBalancer. 

see https://matthewpalmer.net/kubernetes-app-developer/articles/service-kubernetes-example-tutorial.html

Comment: With this answer I get this error `getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND example-mongodb-0.example-mongodb-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local`.
EDIT: this error only seems to happen with the MongoDB Compass GUI. Using e.g. the C# nuget client it works.

Comment: @DavidS. Try setting `useUnifiedTopology` as `false` and only port-forward the replicaset primary pod. Then in the connection string only pass the primary pod's hostname and no replicaset name.

Answer (score 2):

`kubectl port-forward mongodb-replicaset-0 --namespace mongodb-replicaset 27017:27017`

`mongodb-replicaset-0` - pod that runs primary set.

This forwards the traffic to `localhost:27017` on your machine.

[Github discussion](https://github.com/helm/charts/issues/1569)

[Documentation on port-forward](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/)

Comment: Here you are forwarding to the pod called `mongodb-replicaset-0`.  A pod doesn't "run" a replica set, and there is no such thing as a "primary set".  The pod is the thing that is replicated.  It's also good to know that the replica/pod that is primary may change.

Answer (score 0):

After you execute `kubectl get pods`, you will see the name of your pods.

You can connect to any pod using this command: `kubectl exec -it POD_NAME /bin/bash`. 
Also check docs for [Execute a command in a container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#exec).

Also, after connecting to a `POD`, you can check where is mongo located using `whereis mongo`.

I think default installation is located at `/usr/bin/mongo`, so while being connected to your cluster you can call `mongo` directly from any pod you like using `kubectl exec -it POD_NAME /usr/bin/mongo`.